# Extracting member-accesses from an expression in C#

Tags: c#, comparative-review

I need to extract all member accesses to expression parameter (and make sure, that they are not nested). For instance, for expression: `a => a.A + a.B` I need to receive list `{"A", "B"}`. For expression `a => a.B.C` exception should be thrown, as we have nested member access.

I wrote the following class, but I'm not too satisfied with it. Mainly because I don't like pattern "Call, then access member for result", because it decreases code maintainability and allows introducing hard to find bugs (ie. what if I accidentally access results later without calling etc.)

I'm wondering, if this class might be implemented in such way, so that I could call:

```
List<string> members = new MemberExpressionVisitor<A, bool>().GetMembers(a => a.A + a.B);
```

My current solution follows:

```
private class MemberExpressionVisitor<T1, T2> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private Expression<Func<T1, T2>> originalExpression = null;
    private HashSet<string> accessedMembers = null;

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (originalExpression == null)
        {
            if (node is Expression<Func<T1, T2>> startExpression)
            {
                originalExpression = startExpression;
                accessedMembers = new HashSet<string>();

                var result = base.Visit(node);

                originalExpression = null;

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Passed expression must be of type Expression<Func<{typeof(T1).Name},{typeof(T2).Name}>>!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is MemberExpression)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Nested member accesses are not allowed!");

        if (node.Expression is ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
        {
            if (parameterExpression.Name == originalExpression.Parameters[0].Name)
                accessedMembers.Add(node.Member.Name);
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    public List<string> GetAccessedMembers() => accessedMembers.ToList();           
}
```

Example call:

```
public class B
{
    public int P => 5;
}

public class A
{
    public B B => new B();
    public int C => 8;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<A, bool>> exp = a => a.B != null && a.C ==8;

    MemberExpressionVisitor<A, bool> visitor = new MemberExpressionVisitor<A, bool>();
    visitor.Visit(exp);

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", visitor.GetAccessedMembers()));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

**Edit:** Safer, but with clumsy "processing" field.

````
private class MemberExpressionExtractor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private bool processing = false;
    private string parameterName;
    private readonly HashSet<string> accessedMembers = new HashSet<string>();

    public List<string> ExtractMembers<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expression)
    {
        try
        {
            processing = true;

            parameterName = expression.Parameters[0].Name;
            accessedMembers.Clear();

            Visit(expression);
        }
        finally
        {
            processing = false;
        }

        return accessedMembers.ToList();
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (!processing)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Use ExtractMembers<T1, T2> instead.");

        return base.Visit(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is MemberExpression)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Nested member accesses are not allowed!");

        if (node.Expression is ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
        {
            if (parameterExpression.Name == parameterName)
                accessedMembers.Add(node.Member.Name);
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Do you really need to only collect member accesses off the original lambda's first parameter?

Answer (score 1):

What if you nested the `MemberExpressionVisitor` class inside another class? Since I like extension methods, create a static class that contains an extension method on `Expression<Func<T,TRes>>` that creates the visitor, runs it and returns the result:

```
static class LambdaExt {
    public static List<string> GetAccessedMemberNames<T, TRes>(this Expression<Func<T, TRes>> startExpr) {
        var v = new MemberExpressionVisitor<T, TRes>();
        v.Visit(startExpr);

        return v.GetAccessedMembers();
    }

    // put MemberExpressionVisitor definition here
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", exp.GetAccessedMemberNames()));
```

Alternatively, you can add a constructor to `MemberExpressionVisitor`:

```
public MemberExpressionVisitor(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> startExpression) {
    originalExpression = startExpression;
    Visit(startExpression);
}
```

remove the `Visit` override entirely, and simplify the extension method to:

```
public static List<string> GetAccessedMemberNames<T, TRes>(this Expression<Func<T, TRes>> startExpr) =>
    new MemberExpressionVisitor<T,TRes>(startExpr).GetAccessedMembers();
```

This has the compiler enforce type safety, assuming you know your lambda expression variables types properly.

Comment: Once you're hiding the `MemberExpressionVisitor`, is there any gain in the type parameters of `MemberExpressionVisitor`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I think you should be able to replace `Expression<Func<T1,T2>>` with `LambdaExpression` and it should all work.